# Manipulating the plots obtained from NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, manipulate, webmathematica

I am trying to manipulate my parameters eNA, eNM, eMA, eMN, eAM, eAN in the following plot obtained from using NDSolve on my set of differential equations. But I can't find a way to do it. The traditional syntax yields me a blank plot and using doing some modifications yields various errors which I am unable to comprehend.

[image: Here is my code and Plot for the NDSolve solutions]

Please help me out ! Any advice would be highly appreciated

Someone below commented that I should include the code itself for people to copy and paste ! So, here it is :

```
ClearAll[M, A, Ne, t]
r = 0.2;
eMA = 1.5;
eMN = 2;
eAM = 1.7;
eAN = 0.8;
eNM = 2;
eNA = 2.6;

sol = NDSolve[{M'[t] == 
      r*(M[t]*(1 - M[t]/1500) - eMA*M[t]*A[t]/1500 - 
         eMN*M[t]*Ne[t]/1500),
     A'[t] == 
      r*(A[t]*(1 - A[t]/1500) - eAM*A[t]*M[t]/1500 - 
         eAN*A[t]*Ne[t]/1500),
     Ne'[t] == 
      r*(Ne[t]*(1 - Ne[t]/1500) - eNM*Ne[t]*M[t]/1500 - 
         eNA*Ne[t]*A[t]/1500),
     M[0] == 400, A[0] == 400, Ne[0] == 400}, {M[t], A[t], Ne[t]}, {t,
      0, 150}] // Quiet;
M[t_] = M[t] /. sol[[1]][[1]] // Quiet;
A[t_] = A[t] /. sol[[1]][[2]] // Quiet;
Ne[t_] = Ne[t] /. sol[[1]][[3]] // Quiet;
Plot[{M[t], A[t], Ne[t]}, {t, 0, 40}, PlotRange -> {0, 1600}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"M", "A", "Ne"}]
```

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 1):

It is bad practice and dangerous to use the same symbol name in the ODE and for the solution function.
Anyway, with the code below you can play with your parameters.

```
ClearAll[M, A, Ne, t]
r = 0.2;
Manipulate[
 sol = NDSolve[{M'[t] == 
     r*(M[t]*(1 - M[t]/1500) - eMA*M[t]*A[t]/1500 - 
        eMN*M[t]*Ne[t]/1500), 
    A'[t] == 
     r*(A[t]*(1 - A[t]/1500) - eAM*A[t]*M[t]/1500 - 
        eAN*A[t]*Ne[t]/1500), 
    Ne'[t] == 
     r*(Ne[t]*(1 - Ne[t]/1500) - eNM*Ne[t]*M[t]/1500 - 
        eNA*Ne[t]*A[t]/1500), M[0] == 400, A[0] == 400, 
    Ne[0] == 400}, {M[t], A[t], Ne[t]}, {t, 0, 150}];
 M1[t_] = M[t] /. sol[[1]][[1]] // Quiet;
 A1[t_] = A[t] /. sol[[1]][[2]] // Quiet;
 Ne1[t_] = Ne[t] /. sol[[1]][[3]] // Quiet;
 Plot[{M1[t], A1[t], Ne1[t]}, {t, 0, 40}, PlotRange -> {0, 1600}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"M", "A", "Ne"}]
 , {{eMA, 1.5}, 1, 2}, {{eMN, 2}, 1, 3}, {{eAM, 1.7}, 1, 
  2}, {{eAN, 0.8}, 0.5, 1}, {{eNM, 2}, 1, 3}, {{eNA, 2.6}, 2, 3}, 
 TrackedSymbols :> {eMA, eMN, eAM, eAN, eNM, eNA}]
```

[image]